# Lightning Superbadge getting ERROR state on load of compoent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, superbadges

Getting **ERROR** state on a load of a component, Apex class is working fine issue somewhere in JS, but I don't know where it is failing.

JS code

```
({
    onSearch : function(cmp,evt,hlp) {
        var recordId = null;  
        var action = cmp.get("c.getBoats");
        action.setParams({
            boatTypeId: recordId
        });                 
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state == "SUCCESS") {
                console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else if(state == "ERROR"){
                var errors = response.getError();
                console.log(errors)

            }
        });            
        $A.enqueueAction(action);      
    }
})
```

Apex Class

```
public with sharing class BoatSearchResults {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Boat__c> getBoats(String boatTypeId){
        List<Boat__c> lstBoat;
        try{
            String soql = 'SELECT Id,Name,BoatType__c,Description__c,Geolocation__c,Length__c,Price__c,Year_Built__c FROM Boat__c';
            soql = String.isNotBlank(boatTypeId) ? soql + ' WHERE BoatType__c =:'+boatTypeId : soql;
            System.debug('data::'+(List<Boat__c>)Database.query(soql));
            lstBoat = (List<Boat__c>)Database.query(soql);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('eee::'+e.getMessage());
        }
        System.debug('lstBoat::'+lstBoat);
        return lstBoat;
    }
}
```

Console
[image]

Comment: Try this query:   if (boatTypeID != ''){lstBoat=[SELECT Id,Name,BoatType__c,Description__c,Geolocation__c,Length__c,Price__c,Year_Built__c FROM Boat__c  where BoatType__c =:boatTypeID];} return boatType;

Comment: Apex logic is correct, i am getting data as well in debug logs, getting error in lighting

Comment: can you please add the response in Javascript side and debug Logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your dynamic string SOQL query is malformed.  You have:

```
' WHERE BoatType__c =:'+boatTypeId
```

This is putting a `:` in front of the raw record Id, which makes the string look like:

```
' WHERE BoatType__c =:00X000000000000AAA'
```

The correct way to build the string is either 1) with `'` around the record ID without the `:`, or 2) build the variable itself into the string with the `:`

Ex 1)

```
' WHERE BoatType__c = \'' + boatTypeId + '\''
```

Ex 2)

```
' WHERE BoatType__c =:boatTypeId'
```